# How to import python script using ROS and unittest

Tags: python-2.x, python-unittest, ros

I'm facing an issue in a ROS (Python 2.7) project.

**Strucure**

I'm working on a ROS project. The structure is the following:

```
probable-adventure
 |
 |-catkin_ws
   |-src
     |-ros_rover
       |-include
       |-launch
       |-msg
         |-__init__.py
         |-Commands.msg
         |-Teleoperation.msg
       |-scripts
         |-__init__.py
         |-keyboard.py
       |-test
         |-__init__.py
         |-testing.py
     |-__init__.py
 |-CMakeLists.txt
 |-package.xml
```

**Keyboard node (secondary problem)**

`keyboard.py` starts as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy

from ros_rover.msg import Teleoperation
```

I describe it as a secondary problem because if I compile the project from `catkin_ws` directory using `catkin_make` command, everything works well and I can run the keyboard ROS node perfectly even though I get a `pylint` error in the `from ros_rover.msg ...` line.

`Unable to import 'ros_rover.msg'`

**Main Problem**

I just wrote the previous as context. The point is that I have to test the code within the scripts directory. I'm using `unittest` and I create python files in `test` directory.

I have create the following simple test (testing.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import unittest

from scripts.keyboard import GetKey

class TestBareBones(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one_equals_one(self):
        self.assertEquals(1, 1, "1!=1")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I think I have a problem with the imports because if I run the following python commands (from the `ros_rover` directory):

`user@dubuntu:~/probable-adventure/catkin_ws/src/ros_rover$ python testing.py`

`user@dubuntu:~/probable-adventure/catkin_ws/src/ros_rover$ python -m testing`

I get the following error:

```
File "/home/diego/Documents/probable-adventure/catkin_ws/src/ros_rover/test/prueba.py", line 5, in <module>
    from scripts.keyboard import GetKey
File "scripts/keyboard.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ros_rover.msg import Teleoperation
ImportError: No module named ros_rover.msg
```

**My thought**

I think the problem is related with imports because I have read that python imports depends on the directory from where you run the python command.

I run the test from `ros_rover` directory because the test's import is `scripts.keyboard` so it can found it (scripts is in `ros_rover`). But when the `keyboard.py` tries to import `ros_rover.msg` fails because I'm already in `ros_rover` directory and cannot find `ros_rover`.

I have read a lot here in StackOverflow and out of it but I didn't find a solution (I have added a empty `__init__.py` file to ros_rover, scripts and test directories).

Comment: Did you run `catkin_make` to compile the .msg into a usable python definition? You have to add it to your CMakeLists.txt (https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv)

Comment: Sure. As I said in the description I have ran the ROS code and it works properly. The keyboard node publish my custom Teleoperation message over a topic. The problems arised when I tried to create and run the unit test example.

Comment: Ok. This probably still isn't an answer, but have you tried https://wiki.ros.org/unittest ? I'm more familiar with unit testing c++, but calling launch/test files and using rostest seems to be the more blessed way of getting it to work. I suspect the issue is that, to find the msgs, which are hidden in generated ros pkgs under devel/, you can't use vanilla python without importing a part of ros that knows where those msgs are.